# How to show my app icon in the Contacts Android app for user contacts that are registered?

Tags: java, android, spring

I want to have my app's icon displayed in the Contacts Android native app, next to registered contacts phone number. Just like Whatsapp's icon is shown to allow direct messaging from the Contacts app. Do I need the contact list from the server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: - List item check out below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070155/android-check-contacts-if-they-are-registered-in-an-app

Comment: @MuhammadIkram its not OP want . you provided wrong link . Link is about fetching contact and send to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display your app icon in  User's contact app if that number is register with your app .

So for that you need a `SyncAdapter` .

For detail Information about how it works . Please visit [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter#java).

If you need any demo you can check [SyncAdapter Example](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/)